# Sencha Touch Panel Layout: update panel view when the child List changes

Tags: list, layout, panel, sencha-touch

I created a panel containing a List and a button in bottom toolbar.

the panel contains one list and one button; the store of the list gets the data about list of all visible layers in a map; i am using a createStore() function to create this store and pass it to List.store in List initComponent(); since in other operations, user can change a layer's visibility, which will change the list of visible layers; I want to re-load or update the list store before its parent panel shows up each time. currently i call createStore() and re-bind List.store, then use Panel.doComponenetLayout() which I thought it will adjust each children components' positions. but failed.

anybody can help me out of this?

thanks!~

Answer (score 1):

What you probably want to do is something like this:

```
myStore.on('load',function() {
    otherStore.proxy.setUrl('....');
    otherStore.load()
}
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. i am not using proxy/url to provide data for store. i am using inline data. so what am i gonna do?

Comment: You could apply a filter. I'm not sure what you want to accomplish with your panel data when the child data changes.

Comment: sorry for not explaining it well.

Comment: I'm a little confused - if the data is inline, how would it be "updated"?

Comment: the panel contains one list and one button; the store of the list gets the data about list of all visible layers in a map; i am using a createStore() function to create this store and pass it to List.store in List initComponent(); since in other operations, user can change a layer's visibility, which will change the list of visible layers; I want to re-load or update the list store before its parent panel shows up each time. currently i call createStore() and re-bind List.store, then use Panel.doComponenetLayout() which I thought it will adjust each children components' positions. but failed.